# Can not deploy gatsby site to Netlify with fontawesome pro

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, gatsby, netlify, contentful

I have a static site built with Gatstbyjs + contentful. When I try to build and deploy it through Netlify, I encounter some weird problems.

After examing my code, I still couldn't find a fix for it. Build works perfectly fine locally, and it seems like the problem only exists when I try to build it through Netlify. I'm guessing this has to do with the FontAwesome Pro plugin needs an access token in order to be accessed through NPM on Netlify? I have the plugin configured with the access token locally on my machine, but not sure how to do it with Netlify. Does this mean I have to remove this plugin altogether?

Here is the error log:

```
11:21:33 PM: Build ready to start
11:21:36 PM: build-image version: 9e0f207a27642d0115b1ca97cd5e8cebbe492f63
11:21:36 PM: build-image tag: v3.3.2
11:21:36 PM: buildbot version: ef8d0929ed0baabafd8bbb7d0b021e1fc24180c0
11:21:36 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
11:21:36 PM: Starting to download cache of 255.0KB
11:21:36 PM: Finished downloading cache in 86.678513ms
11:21:36 PM: Starting to extract cache
11:21:36 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
11:21:36 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
11:21:37 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
11:21:37 PM: git clone https://github.com/sniperyork/theconcord
11:21:39 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
11:21:39 PM: Starting build script
11:21:39 PM: Installing dependencies
11:21:41 PM: Downloading and installing node v10.16.0...
11:21:41 PM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.16.0/node-v10.16.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
11:21:41 PM: 
#################
11:21:41 PM:                      23.9%
11:21:42 PM: 
####################################################################
11:21:42 PM: #### 100.0%
11:21:42 PM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
11:21:42 PM: Checksums matched!
11:21:44 PM: Now using node v10.16.0 (npm v6.9.0)
11:21:45 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.6.2, read from environment
11:21:46 PM: Using ruby version 2.6.2
11:21:46 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
11:21:46 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
11:21:46 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
11:21:47 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 6.9.0
11:21:50 PM: npm
11:21:50 PM: WARN deprecated @babel/polyfill@7.4.4:  As of Babel 7.4.0, this
11:21:50 PM: npm WARN deprecated package has been deprecated in favor of directly
11:21:50 PM: npm WARN deprecated including core-js/stable (to polyfill ECMAScript
11:21:50 PM: npm WARN deprecated features) and regenerator-runtime/runtime
11:21:50 PM: npm WARN deprecated (needed to use transpiled generator functions):
11:21:50 PM: npm WARN deprecated
11:21:50 PM: npm WARN deprecated   > import "core-js/stable";
11:21:50 PM: npm
11:21:50 PM:  WARN deprecated   > import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
11:21:56 PM: npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
11:22:00 PM: npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
11:22:00 PM: npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
11:22:01 PM: npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.8 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
11:22:08 PM: npm ERR! code E404
11:22:08 PM: npm ERR!
11:22:08 PM:  404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@fortawesome%2fpro-light-svg-icons - Not found
11:22:08 PM: npm ERR!
11:22:08 PM: 404
11:22:08 PM: npm
11:22:08 PM:  ERR! 404  '@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons@^5.9.0' is not in the npm registry.
11:22:08 PM: npm ERR!
11:22:08 PM:  404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
11:22:08 PM: npm
11:22:08 PM:  ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'repo'
11:22:08 PM: npm ERR!
11:22:08 PM:  404
11:22:08 PM: npm ERR!
11:22:08 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
11:22:08 PM: 404 Note that you can also install from a
11:22:08 PM: npm ERR!
11:22:08 PM:  404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
11:22:08 PM: npm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers) you should create a `.npmrc` file in the root of your project (or where you have your package.json file) containing:

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=TOKEN
```

then install the latest version of the pro library using yarn or npm.

Then you import them in app.js as usual and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!